# How to remove border from the custom dialog window?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-widget, customdialog

I have made the custom dialog for my application.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ClkBtn);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog = new Dialog(ExPopup.this);
            myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);
            myDialog.setTitle("My Dialog");
            myDialog.setCancelable(true);
            Button button = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            myDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

But in this I got the border with custom dialogbox. I dont want that border. Then what should i have to remove border from that custom dialog ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the dialog's window content view. I think you can use this in your dialog constructor:

```
this.getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_view);
```

Where "your_dialog_view" should be your new window view for the custom dialog.. :D

Comment: Thanks for reply. I i have to make the Stlyle for the custom dialog and then have set that theme for myCustom Dialog. And it solve my problem.

Comment: I am glad you found the solution! :)